# VS 2012 Durandal intelicence

Tags: durandal

I started using Durandal . The intelicencedoesn't working . I referenced the js to the _refernce.js, but still not working.

any idea ?
Thanks in advance ...

Comment: can you please post some more detail and possibly your code

Answer (score 0):

Durandal is built entirely using AMD modules.  Require modules, by default, don't really have any Intellisense support in Visual Studio.

Looks like there is a way to get it working.  There's a blog post here that may help you if you're using Visual Studio 2012:  http://landofjoe.com/blog/ill-take-my-durandal-with-intellisense-please